# Use of setof/3 with recursive call in GOAL gets wrong, why?

Tags: xml, prolog, prolog-setof

I have problems using `setof/3`, some results are missing.

The context:

I load a xml-file using SWI-Prolog load_xml() to get a recursive
list element (see testelement in the example). Then I want to look 
up specific elements in this list (in the xml tree).
Using `findall/3` combined with `sort/2`, it works fine. But if 
I use `setof/3`, I miss one result. I suppose that `setof/3` has problems due
to the recursive call in `askElement/3` to get/keep the elements? Knows anyone another 
solution to get the elements out of the recursive list?

My test code:

```
testElement([element('recipeml',[version=0.5], 
    [element('recipe',[],
        [element('head',[],
            [element('title',[],['Spaghetti Bolognese']
            )]
        ),
        element('ing-div',[type=titled], 
            [element('title',[],['sauce']),
             element('ingredients',[],
                [element('ing',[],
                    [element('item',[],['hackfleisch']),
                     element('item',[],['fleischtomaten']),
                     element('item',[],['zwiebeln']),
                     element('item',[],['sellerie']
                    )]
                )]
            )]
        )]
    ),
    element('recipe',[],
        [element('head',[],
            [element('title',[],['Erbsensuppe']
            )]
        ),
        element('ing-div',[type=titled], 
            [element('title',[],['elementar']),
             element('ingredients',[],
                [element('ing',[],
                    [element('item',[],['sahne']),
                     element('item',[],['erbsen']),
                     element('item',[],['gemüsebrühe']
                    )]
                )]
            )]
        )]
    )] 
)]).

askElement(Name, Child, Parent) :-
    (
        member( element(Name,_,Child),Parent)
    ;
        member( element(_,_,NewParent),Parent),
        [_|_] = NewParent,
        askElement(Name, Child, NewParent)
    ).

allRecipes_findall(RecipeName) :-
    testElement(Knot),
    findall(TmpR,(askElement('head',HKnot,Knot),askElement('title',TmpR,HKnot)),Bag),
    sort(Bag, RecipeName).

allRecipes_setof(RecipeName) :-
    testElement(Knot),
    setof(TmpR,(askElement('head',HKnot,Knot),askElement('title',TmpR,HKnot)),RecipeName).
```

My Output:

```
3 ?- allRecipes_findall(X).
X = [['Erbsensuppe'], ['Spaghetti Bolognese']].

4 ?- allRecipes_setof(X).
X = [['Erbsensuppe']]
```

I expected that in both case I get

```
X = [['Erbsensuppe'], ['Spaghetti Bolognese']].
```

What's wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

PS: Every comment/review of my (first try of) Prolog code is very welcome :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `setof/3` predicate gives you a solution per each different instantiation of the free variables in the goal. Using your code as-is gives:

```
?- allRecipes_findall(X).
X = [['Erbsensuppe'], ['Spaghetti Bolognese']].

?- allRecipes_setof(X).
X = [['Erbsensuppe']] ;
X = [['Spaghetti Bolognese']].
```

That's the expected result. You can, however, make `setof/3` ignore the free variables by existentially quantifying them using the `^/2` operator:

```
allRecipes_setof(RecipeName) :-
    testElement(Knot),
    setof(TmpR,HKnot^(askElement('head',HKnot,Knot),askElement('title',TmpR,HKnot)),RecipeName).
```

With this change you'll get the same result as with the `findall/3` predicate:

```
?- allRecipes_setof(X).
X = [['Erbsensuppe'], ['Spaghetti Bolognese']].
```

Regarding comments on your programming style, use underscores instead of CamelCase in *atoms* for code readability. E.g. `ask_element` instead of `askElement`. For *variables*, on the other hand, CamelCase is often used.

Comment: Great :-) In my larger program I did a cut (!) so I was not aware Prolog would have more than 1 solution. And in my simple example I just forgot to type a ";". Great, thanks, that helps. And the ^/2 operator, to be honest, is new to me...as the whole prolog stuff... The way I run through the testElement is more or less ok/efficient?

Comment: I suggest you use a different representation in the third argument of the `element/3` term in order to easily distinguish between child and non-child elements instead of using a list in both cases. This would allow you to improve the definition of the `askElement/3` predicate. Note that `[_|_]` also unifies with e.g. `['Spaghetti Bolognese']` so you're not making the two cases exclusive.

Comment: Thanks again :-) With your first suggestion, I am not sure what you mean. Should I give the element 'title' in the path 'recipe-head-title' a unique name to distinguish it from 'recipe-ingdiv-title', so I do not need to call askElement twice? I can't do this as I want to use a given xml-format. Or do you mean something else? Thanks for the remark concerning '[_|_]', I will change it to 'is_list'.

Comment: I mean using a representation such as `element(..., ..., child(Child))` for leaf nodes and `element(..., ..., descendants([Descendant1, ...]))` or simply `element(..., ..., [Descendant1, ...])` for nodes with descendants. I.e. make the third argument of `element/3` term use **different** functors.

Comment: oh, uups. Now I got it. Good idea :-) Then I only have to look for a child when looking for an element. I will think about it. As I got the testElement from load_xml in SWI-Prolog, I will probably transform it in your suggested representation once before further use. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Paulo already give plenty of advice about your current code. I'm here only to suggest to take advantage of library([xpath](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/xpath.pl)) when you need to handle XML. It does require a bit of exercise, but then you are rewarded with much functionality... for your example:

```
?- [library(xpath)].
true.

?- testElement(E), xpath(E, //head//title(text), T).
...
T = 'Spaghetti Bolognese' ;
...
T = 'Erbsensuppe' ;
false.
```

Comment: Wow!     (_filler text due to speechlessness_)

Comment: `use_module(library(xpath))`

Comment: Thanks again. It works in both versions:                             `:- use_module(library(xpath)).` or
`:- [library(xpath)].`